# Existence of global attractor in duffing equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

How to prove the existence and identify global attractor in Duffing equation
$$\ddot{x}+\epsilon \dot{x}+x^3-ax=0$$
where $\epsilon >0$ and $a>0$?

I found a definition:

A bounded closed set $A_1 \subset X$ is called a global attractor for a dynamical system $(X, S_t)$, if

- $A_1$ is an invariant set
- the set $A_1$ uniformly attracts all trajectories starting in bounded sets, i.e. for any bounded set $B$ from $X$
  $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \sup \lbrace \operatorname{dist}(S_t y, A_1): y\in B \rbrace=0$$
  where $\operatorname{dist}(z,A)=\inf\lbrace\operatorname{d}(z,y): y\in A\rbrace$ where $\operatorname{d}(z,y)$ is the distance between the elements $z$ and $y$ in $X$.

I finished only ODE course and I don't know a lot about dynamical systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation describes a mechanical system with friction/energy dissipation. Or in formulas
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac12\dot x^2+\frac14(x^2-a)^2\right]=-ϵ\dot x^2.
$$
So as long as the particle the system describes is in motion, it will lose energy and move down to one of the minima $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$, which both are stable equilibrium points of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

This DE can be written as

$$
\dot x = y\\
\dot y = a x-x^3-\epsilon y
$$

with equilibrium points

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & \text{type} \\
 0 & 0 & \text{saddle}\\
 -\sqrt{a} & 0 & \text{sink}\\
 \sqrt{a} & 0 & \text{sink}\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

This qualification is done according to the jacobian eigenvalues

$$
J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 a-3 x^2 & -\epsilon \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

Attached an orbit for $a = 1, \epsilon = 0.1, x_0 = 2, y_0 = 1$

Comment: I have an intuition about that, and i guess that the points $(-\sqrt{a},0)$, $(\sqrt{a},0)$ will be attractors (it depends on initial conditions to wchich point the trajectories converge). But linearization theorem tells something only locally,  in the neighbourhood of equilibrium points, not globally and I'm not sure is this a good way to argument that.

Comment: This is what the standard theory says. Of course you can see it as well as a dissipative system.  The best way is by exhibition of a Lyapunov function. This Lyapunov function could be $\frac 12 \dot x^2+\frac 14(x^2-a)^2+\int \dot x^2 dt \ge 0$... but this is not a conventional Lyapunov function.